# Issue with group by statement

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run this query but I keep getting this error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function 00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function". How should I Group By in this case?

```
select trunc(dstamp) "DATE", COUNT(CODE), user_id,  dstamp - lag(dstamp) over (partition by user_id order by dstamp) as elapsed, 
ROUND(sum(update_qty / substr(sku_id, instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1) +1 , instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 2) - 1 - instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1)))) "CASES_PICKED",
from v_inventory_transaction
where client_id = 'USKIDS2CA' 
and code = 'Pick' 
and list_id IS NOT NULL 
and STATION_ID LIKE 'R%' 
and reference_id not like '%-FK%' 
AND trunc(dstamp) = '03/23/2022'
GROUP BY ***????***
```

Comment: Why is there a comma after "CASES_PICKED" followed by a FROM Clause.  I'd think it would complain about that first... is this the full query?  This issn't mySQL which extends the group by to a degree where one isn't required.

Comment: You need to include column for `group by` if no aggregate functions used in `select` `(count, sum, min, max...)`

Comment: the query appears incomplete, you are attempting to divide using a substring and you are attempting to use a window function needing details that would not exist after grouping

Comment: [ORA-00937](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903): **Cause**: A SELECT list cannot include both a group function, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, and an individual column expression, unless the individual column expression is included in a GROUP BY clause.

**Action**: Drop either the group function or the individual column expression from the SELECT list or add a GROUP BY clause that includes all individual column expressions listed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the usage of the analytic function `lag` in the `GROUP BY`statement.

The correct approach is to *first* calculate the column with the `lag`

```
SELECT trunc(dstamp) "DATE", user_id, 
dstamp - lag(dstamp) over (partition by user_id order by dstamp) as elapsed
FROM tab
```

and in the *second* step use it in some aggregate function - here example with `max`

```
WITH dt AS (
SELECT trunc(dstamp) "DATE", user_id, 
dstamp - lag(dstamp) over (partition by user_id order by dstamp) as elapsed
FROM tab
)
SELECT  "DATE", user_id, max(elapsed)
FROM dt
GROUP BY "DATE", user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all aggregations/calculations temporarily

```
, trunc(dstamp) - lag(trunc(dstamp)) OVER (
    PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY trunc(dstamp)
    ) AS elapsed
, COUNT(CODE)
, ROUND(sum(update_qty / ??? )) "CASES_PICKED"
```

it will help you focus on the underlying needs of the group by clause, which without those calculations is almost a replica of the select clause (but also without any column aliases).

```
SELECT
      trunc(dstamp) "DATE"
    , user_id
    , substr(sku_id, instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1) + 1
            , instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 2) - 1 - instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1)) "SUBSTRING"
FROM v_inventory_transaction
WHERE client_id = 'USKIDS2CA'
    AND code = 'Pick'
    AND list_id IS NOT NULL
    AND STATION_ID LIKE 'R%'
    AND reference_id NOT LIKE '%-FK%'
    AND trunc(dstamp) = '03/23/2022'
GROUP BY
      trunc(dstamp)
    , user_id
    , substr(sku_id, instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1) + 1
            , instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 2) - 1 - instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1))
```

**However** there are at least these problems to overcome if we attempt to finish the query

- it isn't clear (without sample data and expected result) to know if you need the "elapsed" calculation performed before the grouping or if it is sufficient to do this using the truncated date.
- you cannot divide a number by a string eg `100/substr('bad',1,2)` is bad and produces `ORA-01722: invalid number` as a result. You could try casting the substring to a numeric - but this could fail also if the string can be converted.
- compare the truncated date to a date, not a string e.g. `trunc(dstamp) = date '2022-03-23'` or use `to_date()`

Suggested:

```
SELECT
      trunc(dstamp) "DATE"
    , user_id
    , trunc(dstamp) - lag(trunc(dstamp)) OVER (
        PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY trunc(dstamp)
        ) AS elapsed
    , COUNT(CODE)
    , ROUND(sum(update_qty / cast(substr(sku_id, instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1) + 1
        , instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 2) - 1 - instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1)) as integer))) "CASES_PICKED"
FROM v_inventory_transaction
WHERE client_id = 'USKIDS2CA'
    AND code = 'Pick'
    AND list_id IS NOT NULL
    AND STATION_ID LIKE 'R%'
    AND reference_id NOT LIKE '%-FK%'
    AND trunc(dstamp) = to_date('03/23/2022','mm/dd/yyyy')
GROUP BY
      trunc(dstamp)
    , user_id
    , cast(substr(sku_id, instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1) + 1
         , instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 2) - 1 - instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1)) as integer)
```

note: to use the lag function you should refer to `trunc(dstamp)` throughout otherwise you would need to group by the un-truncated dstamp

see: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b2fa96ca04b40ea4cd8ecd6d33bc6292)*